# std::copy with parameters that may be unsafe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, copy, c++14

so I have a piece of old code that I'm trying to debug

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> filters;

  ...
  for (auto filterIter : filters)
{
   ...
   wchar_t* nameArray = new wchar_t[filterIter.first.size() + 1];
   std::copy(filterIter.first.begin(), filterIter.first.end(), nameArray);
   nameArray[filterIter.first.size()] = '\0';
   ...
   LPCWSTR pszName = nameArray;
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I get this warning saying:

```
warning C4996: 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
```

I want to resolve this warning without having to silence the warning. I know that the problem is the fact that nameArray is a regular pointer not an [Output iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) . And std::copy wants me to put in an output iterator in std::copy last parameter. I want to make this code comply with what std::copy wants me to do. What's an elegant way of accomplishing that?

I did think about making my own iterator class but is that really that elegant?

Comment: You gave `std::copy` what it expects. From a pure C++ perspective, there's nothing wrong with the call to `std::copy`.

Comment: What should I do then to turn off the warning?

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why are you allocating with `new` and using `std::copy`?

Comment: I guess because `nameArray` is later assigned to this variable called `pszName` where `pszName` is #defined as a wchar_t

Comment: What should you do then to turn off the warning? what about reading the whole warning (it literally says how to)!

Comment: -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question as I figured I think I've figured it out and it would help others who runs into this problem:

it turns out, this is a very C way of copying. Since `LPCWSTR` is simply a wchar_t under the hood, I end up just doing this and I don't get compiler errors anymore. I'm going to run test to make sure this function still behaves the same.

Note: I didn't write this code, this is simply a legacy code I'm looking at.

Here is the updated version

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> filters;

  ...
  for (auto filterIter : filters)
{
  ...
  LPCWSTR pszName = filterIter.first.c_str();
  ...
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```